# DOMDocument: how to append after <title> tag

Tags: php, domdocument

I have the following code and it works good so far.

However, I try to attach the `<link href=".." ../>` tag below the `<title>` tag OR, better yet, below my last `<meta>` tag.

Is there a way to accomplish this with DOMDocument?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html_data);

$element = $dom->createElement( 'link');
$element->setAttribute( 'rel', 'stylesheet' );
$element->setAttribute( 'type', 'text/css' );
$element->setAttribute( 'href', $url );
$element->setAttribute( 'media', isset($media) ? $media : 'screen' );

$head = $dom->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0);
$head->appendChild($element);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Wait.  What's the question here?  Your code works fine.  It appends a `<link>` tag to the end of the `<head>`.  I don't think the order of tags in the `<head>` matters.  http://codepad.org/xdy6dlHS

Comment: Hello @meagar,
you're right, the _<link>_ tag will be put correctly into the _<head>_ section.

However, in some cases jQuery Plugins will return broken DOM if you put its CSS scripts AFTER the jQuery plugin.

Thus I need a solution to put the CSS files next below the <title> and the JS Files as "last childs" of the <head> section.

Comment: You meant to reply to @Rocket. I didn't not make that comment.

Comment: you're right.
I am new here and still lil'bit confused with the mechanics of this platform. ;-)